# Sort Imported HTML Table in Google Sheets

Tags: sorting, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I would like to sort [THIS TABLE](https://dividendhistory.org/monthly-payout/) in a Google sheet after I import it using `=IMPORTHTML("https://dividendhistory.org/monthly-payout/","table",1)`. It appears to sort momentarily when applied, but immediately reverts to the order supplied by the import.

Comment: What formula are you using to sort the data and how are you trying to sort it, by the first column, ascending or how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [query function](https://www.benlcollins.com/spreadsheets/google-sheets-query-sql/) is probably your best option.

For sorting on `Col1` **ascending** use:

```
=query(IMPORTHTML("https://dividendhistory.org/monthly-payout/","table",1),"select * order by Col1 ASC",1)
```

For `Col4` **descending** it changes to:

```
=query(IMPORTHTML("https://dividendhistory.org/monthly-payout/","table",1),"select * order by Col4 DESC",1)
```

[Example spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1dQiSA8bAEI82hW07Q2Wet6bthUDCZF7IpXe_8udNPMU/)

Comment: "Pretty Good" answer! Exactly what I needed. The example spreadsheet was brilliant. Many thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the `PGP` call out...